# Vuex Store - Variable updates only in Store, not globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

**Solved: I did not notice i used the wrong Variable**

I'am trying to access a store value after i have mutated it in a component.
First, i select an array of numbers from a list, which then after a button is pressed gets stored in in the store. When i try to Access the Value from the store it is still empty.

My Vue Component:

```
<template>
   <MultiSelect
        class="groupselect"
        v-model="localSelectedNumbers"
        :options="options"
        optionLabel="id"
        placeholder="Wähle Geräte"


    />
  <v-btn @click="refresh()">Click</v-btn>
  <p>{{selectedNumbers}}</p>
</template>
<script>
import MultiSelect from "primevue/multiselect";
import {mapMutations, mapState} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Gerateauswahl",
  components: {MultiSelect},
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
        'mode',
        'selectedNumbers',
        'options'
    ])
  },
  data() {
    return {
      localSelectedNumbers: [],
      show: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedNumbers(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.show = newValue
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
        'setRows'
    ]),
    refresh() {
      this.setRows(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.localSelectedNumbers)))
      //console.log(this.selectedNumbers)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My Store:

```
import {createStore} from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            options : [
                {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}
            ],
            rows: [],
            mode: false,
            selectedNumbers: []
        }
    },
mutations: {
        setRows(state, payload) {
            console.log(state.rows)
            state.rows = payload
            console.log(state.rows)
        },
}
export default store;
```

I've tried with watchers, manuel refresh.
The console.log output in the Store: (trying with numbers 1 and 2)

```
<target>: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { id: 1 }
1: Object { id: 2 }
length: 2​​
<prototype>: Array []
<handler>: Object { get: get(target, key, receiver), set: set(target, key, value, receiver), deleteProperty: deleteProperty(target, key), … }
```

but the selectedNumbers Variable in the Vue Component stays empty, as well as the this.$store.state.selectedNumbers when accessed from the Component.

Comment: I think you need to *commit* the *payload. *ex( ```actions: {setRows( { commit },payload){commit('setRows', payload)}``` )*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating `rows` state in the mutation but you calling `selectedNumbers` in the component..
You need to update `selectedNumbers` instead in the mutation **or** call `rows` state in the component

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are updating `rows` in mutation but you are watching `selectedNumbers`. I think your mutation should look something like this

```
mutations: {
  setRows(state, payload) {
    console.log(state.selectedNumbers);
    state.selectedNumbers = payload.map(item => item.id);
    console.log(state.selectedNumbers);
  },
}
```